# How can I use date picker with time picker together?

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, datetimepicker, material-ui

I just want to use date picker with time picker together? just like the image below.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [react-datetime](https://github.com/YouCanBookMe/react-datetime)

In can use it like

```
handleDateChange = (dateObj) => {
        console.log(moment(dateObj).utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm').toString());
    }
<Datetime dateFormat='YYYY-MM-DD' timeFormat='HH:mm' onBlur={this.handleDateChange.bind(this)}/>
```

`Datetime` gives you a `dateObj` when you provide an event like `onChange` or `onBlur` on it. You can now using libraries like `moment.js` to manipulate the `date and time` format as you want